# Best way to persist a <Header /> with Outlet in React-Router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I think I've over-read docs and confused myself at this point so I'm posting here out of desperation. I'm using React-Router-dom@6 (edited: 6.3 to be exact) and I'm trying to make sure of the `Outlet` feature, to make it a 'placeholder' for components to be rendered.

I've got an `App` component, a `Header` component, and a few other components I'd like to render, which have children-paths of their own -- in addition to having a `/login` route, and a `/signup` route. This is a project ticketmaster style app where a `user` can make a `post` on a `concert`, and find `concerts` either directly or through listings on an `artist`'s page.

My main goal is to persist the `<Header/>` throughout, so that I can store a currentUser and render a currentUser's concerts, and posts.

What I have below is my n-th attempt and how it "should" look (prior to the proper answer coming in this thread, hopefully) --

The App component, and Header component are below.

```
 function App() {

  return (
<div>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' index element={<Header />} />
    <Route path='artists'>
      <Route index element={<AllArtists />} />
      <Route path=':id' element={<ArtistPage />} />
      <Route path='new' element={<CreateArtist />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='concerts'>
          <Route index element={<AllConcerts />} />
          <Route path=':id' element={<ConcertPage />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/login' index element={<Login />} />
        <Route path='/signup' index element={<SignUp />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );


function Header() {

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='bg-zinc-900 navbar text-primary-content'> 
{* rest of Header content here *}
      </div>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'd like to get this initial `App` and `Header` configured properly at least, then extrapolate the `Outlet` 'structure' (for lack of a better phrase) to the child classes once I understand how it's properly done. Any tips on that end are also welcome. I'm assuming even there that, for example, the `AllArtists` component would have an `Outlet` within it that renders `ArtistPage` and `CreateArtist` based on path but I'm not sure of anything anymore. Thank you in advance for any guidance

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I recommend doing just the header content in `<Header>`. Then create a `<Root>` component that includes the `<Header/>` and `<Outlet/>`. This kind of decomposition into components is generally good design when using React.

Comment: Thank you @Code-Apprentice -- I'll look into that and yes, at first glance, I do see how that would make more sense. It definitely cleans things up and orders them properly, which is my exact goal

Answer (score 0):

Do not close tag with layout. Everything inside the tag will use the layout element. For example:

```
<Route
  path="/"
  element={<AdminLayout />}
>
  <Route
    index
    element={<Home />}
  />
  <Route
    path="dashboard"
    element={<Dashboard />}
  />
</Route>
```

In your Code, you have closed the tag of header. You should wrap other routes inside it where you want to use this layout.

```
<Route path='/' index element={<Header />} />
```

it should be

```
<Route path='/' index element={<Header />}>
  //Other routes
</Route>
```

Comment: Ah good catch, I think that was a minor slip-up on my end but will remedy it, thank you!